# Elixir create_all() not creating database and tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm using Elixir 0.7.1 , Sqlalchemy 0.6beta1 , MySQLdb 1.2.2.
My Model file 'model.py' looks like this:

```
from elixir import *
from datetime import datetime

class Author:
  first_name = Field(Unicode(64))
  last_name = Field(Unicode(64))

class Article:
  title = Field(Unicode(64))

class Category:
  name = Field(Unicode(64))

setup_all()
metadata.bind = "mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbname"
metadata.bind.echo = True

create_all()
metadata.create_all()
```

after executing : python model.py , no tables are created and no errors are thrown.
Here is a list of echo'd commands that are issued to the SQL server:

```
2010-03-06 19:50:22,004 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c SELECT DATABASE()
2010-03-06 19:50:22,004 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c ()
2010-03-06 19:50:22,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%%'
2010-03-06 19:50:22,005 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c ()
2010-03-06 19:50:22,006 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2010-03-06 19:50:22,006 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c ()
2010-03-06 19:50:22,007 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c SHOW COLLATION
2010-03-06 19:50:22,007 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c ()
2010-03-06 19:50:22,009 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2010-03-06 19:50:22,010 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...6c4c ()
```

I have searched for a solution and couldn't find any.

Comment: Edit: database already exists, so the title should only mention that it doesn't create the tables.

Comment: I have decided to use Sqlalchemy by itself and using it's orm and declarative approach. It is working now! I will not be using Elixir. It would be good to see what was the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to inherit from the Entity base class (or from another base class of your choosing that use the EntityMeta metaclass).

```
class Author(Entity):
    first_name = Field(Unicode(64))
    last_name = Field(Unicode(64))

class Article(Entity):
    title = Field(Unicode(64))

class Category(Entity):
    name = Field(Unicode(64))
```